# PHP Create Excel Sheet and Place On Hosting ( No Download )

Tags: php, excel, hosting

i am running one file with code

`$filename = "file.xls";

$content = '';

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;

foreach($data as $row) {

if(!$flag) {

echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";

$flag = true;

}

echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";

}`

this help me to save file on system i want when i run this file instead download of excel. this file save excel-file in same folder.

Comment: that's not an excel file, its a text file. want an excel file use [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi easiest way to do this with :

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the script, open de buffer:

```
ob_start();
```

And at the end, save the buffer:

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents($filename, $output);
```

Also you can try [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for a clean spreadsheet generation.

By the way, the directory must have write permissions for Apache user:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/php/script/directory/
```

On Red-Hat/Centos/Fedora:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /path/to/php/script/directory/
```

On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/php/script/directory/
```

Comment: why not just not use echo and write to a file? there's no need for output buttering